# FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Django Rest + Reactjs App

Tags: reactjs, django, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

My web app has a django rest framework backend and reactjs frontend. I want to add firebase push notification service to my web app. According to the tutorials I added the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** in the public folder of the react app which is the frontend. The contents in the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** is as below:

firebase-messaging-sw.js/public

```
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: payload.notification.icon,
  };

  console.log(notificationOptions, notificationTitle);

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

});
```

firebase.js/src

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

file where I generate the token for fcm

```
 const requestPermission = async () => {
    if (Notification.permission === "default") {
      if (user.regd_as === "TCH") {
        NotificationBar(
          `Please click allow for notification accesss so that you can receive notifications when students send you a request.`,
          `info`
        );
      } else {
        NotificationBar(
          `Please click allow for notification accesss so that you can receive notifications when teacher accept your request.`,
          `info`
        );
      }
    }
    try {
      const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

      if (permission === "granted") {
        // Generate token
        const token = await getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey:
            "BJueTNhdRYtjQJ3BqwytPu4MUkK0BrUkuPcnDd3oBCoppBTb-xdJtaRcmu9CLStX6UeltYst--YtMirduz3vGJI",
        });
        if (token) {
          console.log(token);
          let response = await storeNotificationToken(token);
        } else {
          console.log(`token was not produced`);
        }
      } else if (permission === "denied") {
        if (localStorage.getItem("noti_denied_seen") === "true") {
          return;
        }
        if (user.regd_as === "TCH") {
          NotificationBar(
            `Since you have denied notification permission you will miss out notifications when students send you request. Please enable/ allow notification access.`,
            `error`
          );
        } else {
          NotificationBar(
            `Since you have denied notification permission you will miss out notifications when teachers aceepts your request. Please enable/ allow notification access.`,
            `error`
          );
        }

        localStorage.setItem("noti_denied_seen", "true");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // getting user permission for notification
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermission();
  }, []);
```

In developement, that is, when the react app runs seperately at localhost:3000 and django backend runs on 127.0.0.1:8000 the token is generated and the notification is received in my pc.

In production I use the build version of react app, `npm run build`, and serve it with django rest backend. But in production the I get the below firebase error and no token is generated

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mywebsite.in/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://mywebsite.in/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw.ts:43:25
    at p (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.throw (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at Td (asyncToGenerator.js:3:20)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
```

**Question**

How to get rid of this error? Please suggest to me the proper setup for django + react app to run this service worker file for push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

so after reserching I understood that browser was not able to register the service worker and the reason was wrong path, since there is no public folder in the build version therefore the file has to be served by django so that the file is found in the url `https://mywebsite.in/firebase-messaging-sw.js` which is handeled by django. So the following changes were made to make it work

**add the following code to the existing code in firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
    .then((registration) => {
      console.log("Service worker registered:", registration);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Service worker registration failed:", error);
    });
}
```

in django write the following code in a view

**app/views.py**

```
def serve_firebase_sw(request):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'build/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(file_contents, content_type='text/javascript')
```

and add the url in the main project_name/urls.py where urls from other apps are important

**project_name/urls.py**

```
from pushnotification.views import serve_firebase_sw
urlpatterns = [
   path('firebase-messaging-sw.js', serve_firebase_sw),
]
```